# Why am I getting NaNs in R while using ordinal regression (MASS::polr) and fitting an interaction?

Tags: r, regression, ordinal

I am using the polr function for ordinal regression. Without an interaction included results come out fine but as soon as I add the interaction I get 'In sqrt(diag(vc)): NaNs produced. The input and output are:

```r
m1 <- polr(Knowledge.ordinal.ranking ~ Years.fishing*Age + Attitude, 
          data = data, Hess=TRUE)


Call:
polr(formula = Knowledge.ordinal.ranking ~ Years.fishing * Age + 
    Attitude, data = data, Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                      Value Std. Error t value
Years.fishing      0.052128        NaN     NaN
Age                0.022808        NaN     NaN
Attitude           0.160647     0.4904  0.3276
Years.fishing:Age -0.001141        NaN     NaN

Intercepts:
               Value   Std. Error t value
Low|Average    -0.9393     NaN        NaN
Average|Good    1.3745     NaN        NaN
Good|Excellent  2.9114     NaN        NaN

Residual Deviance: 303.3596 
AIC: 317.3596
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

I'm not sure how to add data but Age (18 - 80) and Years.fishing (8 - 60) are continuous and correlated, Attitude is a binary where positive = 1 and negative = 0. Knowledge.ordinal.ranking is a four-part scale - Low, Average, Good, Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if you're still looking for a solution, but I have experienced the same problem. In my case, scaling of the variables in the interaction term helped, as discussed here:
https://stats-stackexchange-com.translate.goog/questions/500396/ordinal-logistic-regression-how-to-handle-nans?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=de&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=sc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).